# Ffmpeg not working in background when target SDK updated to 33

Tags: android, background-process, android-workmanager, ffmpegkit

I am using FFMPEGKit library in my android project. (https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit).

After updating the `targetSdkVersion` of my android app from 31 to 33, the compression feature stopped working in the background. The compression feature used to work in the background or when the app was closed in `targetSdkVersion 31`, but now it stops suddenly after few seconds without any error. I am using work manager for the background task. By the way It's working fine in foreground.

This is the log I'm getting when I put my app in background

`2023-07-27 18:56:03.631 19329-19647 ffmpeg-kit              com.xx.xx          I  frame= 1566 fps= 22 q=13.0 size=   38656kB time=00:00:26.14 bitrate=12111.8kbits/s speed=0.371x     ---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (19329) for package com.xx.xx ----------------------------`

Updating the library from v4.5.LTS to v5.1.LTS did not solve the problem.
Did anyone knows any fix for this?

Comment: Can you share with a simplified implementation of the Work Manager, so we can check the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) and help you?